# how to call javascript from a rails controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form and on the submit, it directs to a 'overlap_check' controller action.
In the action, if a condition is met from the params that have been sent, i want to render a modal on the page by calling a javascript function.
Is this possible?

I've seen some examples using:

```html
# render :js => "('#testing').modal('show');"
```

But no luck with this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) in controller:

```
def overlap_check
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

2) create **overlap_check.js.erb**

3) add js code to **overlap_check.js.erb**

```
('#testing').modal('show');
```

4) add `remote: true` to form

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in Rails 7, it seems like this approach no longer works for Rails 7.

Comment: Yes, this approach doesn't work in Rails 7. Turbo stream can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention below format in controller action.

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
end
```

And create `actioname.js.erb` in views. There you can call `('#testing').modal('show');` .
If you calling controller action by link then add `remote: true`

```
<%= link_to your_link_name, path, :remote => true %>
```

Or If you calling from action then add `remote: true` in your form

Then it should be work.

Comment: thanks, i've done this, however im getting an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error?

Comment: how you calling your controller action, By clicking link? or by form submit?

Comment: i call the controller with form submit

Comment: Then add `remote: true ` in your form. still if you have doubt then send me your form once.

Comment: I hope you got solution :) . Happy coding